# On Mediawiki the notifications does not work. But e-mails for creating an new account are. How can this be solved?

Tags: mediawiki

I use MediaWiki version 1.41.0. Notifications does not work, and I can not find settings were specific control can be made. I have an Admin account, and an account with my own name.
A page I add the notification with the * on the right top. When clicking I see the message "Adding the page in your notification list." So the page notification is marked. I made the notification for my own account, and the I made an edit on that same page with the Admin account. And vice versa does also not work either.

The e-mail system does work. An e-mail is send when creating a new account. I also can send an e-mail to an other user. Only the notifications does not work.

What can be the problem, and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In LocalSettings.php I changed from false to true:

```
$wgEnotifUserTalk = true; 
$wgEnotifWatchlist = true;
```